# Can't get user feed with application access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I'm (just?) trying to get a user's feed via the graph api.  All the permissions are in place; I just need to get it to work.

I've found that, if I go into the graph api explorer, I can retrieve the feed if I pass over an access token corresponding to the user.  However, if I use the application's access token, I get nothing -- it returns with an empty DATA value.

Is this right?  Shouldn't the app's access token work?  What's the point of having it around if it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An App Access token is primarily used for taking actions on behalf of the app itself (e.g. banning users, changing app settings, posting games achievements, etc).

To access a user's posts you need a user access token from them (or from another user who's able to see that user's posts), and the access token needs the `read_stream` permission

Comment: Understood about the read_stream permission; it's granted as part of the login. I guess part of my confusion is in that I'm able to get a user's friends with the app's access token, so it seems like the same thing should happen with the feed. So is this just how the world works?  Thanks much, btw.

Comment: I think yes, impersonated access tokens (Page or App) don't have the same access as user access tokens, especially where the data you're accessing has privacy settings to consider, they're looked at with the permissions of the user whose access token you're using

Comment: So, on the chance that you know, how do I get an access token for an arbitrary user, so I can get their feed?  The code on my site that handles the realtime feed callback isn't logged into facebook as that user (or anybody, really), so the usual route to getting the access token for a currently-logged-in user doesn't apply.  This is seriously kicking my butt...  Thanks much!

Comment: If you want to read a certain user's wall posts, you need either them or one of their friends to auth the app - unless you do this your only real option is to use an access token for yourself and hope that the content you want would be visible to you anyway

Comment: Understood.  Once the user has authorized the app that has requested read_stream, how does my callback then get the access token for that user?  That's the part that's killing me.

Comment: You probably need to look at the sample apps or the [authentication docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) - it's a bit difficult to help here